# Problemas ao integrar pipelines do Bitbucket com heroku

Tags: php, deploy, heroku, bitbucket, pipeline

Estou com um problema ao integrar pipelines do bitbucket com heroku, configurei o arquivo normalmente, e quando ele vai pra parte do build no Heroku ele aparece esta mensagem:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
!     Push rejected, Failed decompressing source code.
Source archive detected as: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
More information: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-deploying-slugs#create-slug-archive
```

Stack de erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha pipeline está assim

```
image: composer:2.0


pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Deploy
            script:
            - zip -r slug.zip .
            - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:0.1.1
              variables:
                HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
                HEROKU_APP_NAME: $HEROKU_APP_NAME
                ZIP_FILE: 'slug.zip'
```

Tentei por meio de tar e não consegui tambem

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei o melhor meio de compactar o fonte com compatibilidade, basta compactar com git

```
script: 
       - git archive --format=tar.gz master -o application.tar.gz
```

Assim deu certo